# How to automatically login to another website every day?

Tags: php, login-script

Is it possible to make a script, which will execute every day at particular time, and this script would login to specific website?

On some sites there are bonuses for each day login so it would be very good thing to automate.

I have only the idea, I have completely no idea how it can be done. Maybe PHP, JavaScript or something else.

Comment: It's possible, yes. Do you need JavaScript in the website to login? If so you'll need a system that supports JavaScript, such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) - that can be remote controlled by JS, PHP and other languages. If not, use something like [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), which is a PHP library. (Questions of this kind are rather broad, and so this is likely to be put on hold. However you should get some hints and ideas in the comments).

Comment: Have you tried looking into cron jobs?  This will automate the execution of whatever script you prepare.  You could set it up to fire on a daily schedule.

Comment: I did not mentioned, the script need to be executed on server, without doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

cron jobs on linux systems or task manager on windows can start a script on fixed intervals. You don't write how you need to login. Most common login systems uses a cookie an the client side. [PHP's curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) can store cookies

Answer (score 3):

Automatic script execution is possible to use Cron jobs which available in PHP engines in most servers.

if you need to make login every day an specific website, i think you don't need to write any script you can put your home page for the login page and you would say remember password for your computer, so every time you open your browser it automatically opens and make login.